# Jackson Validation when mapping JSON to POJO

Tags: json, jackson, mapping, dropwizard, pojo

Firstly I must confess that I am completely new to Web Services and the DropWizard framework.

I am currently performing a POST request and trying to parse the JSON body into a POJO.

This works great when the JSON is in the required format. However, when a key in the JSON, is missing, my POJO resorts to a default value.

My question is, is there anyway of either checking the JSON for all values or having Jackson throw some sort of exception if a JSON key is missing?

```
public class PlacedBetDecimal extends PlacedBet {

    private double odds;

    // Empty constructor to please Jackson
    public PlacedBetDecimal() {

    }

    public PlacedBetDecimal(@JsonProperty("bet_id") long bet_id,
                            @JsonProperty("stake") int stake,
                            @JsonProperty("odds") double odds) {

        super.bet_id = bet_id;
        super.stake = stake;
        this.odds = odds;
    }

    public double getOdds() {
        return odds;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PlacedBetFractional{" +
                "bet_id="+super.bet_id+
                "stake="+super.stake+
                "odds=" + odds +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The JSON which would be in the body is as follows:

```
{
    "bet_id": 1,
    "odds": 11.0,
    "stake": 10
}
```

If for some reason, someone supplied a body with:

```
{
    "odds": 11.0,
    "stake": 10
}
```

Then i would like to be able to catch this instead of Jackson auto filling the bet_id to 0.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `primitives`, use their corresponding type wrappers, e.g. `Double` instead of `double`, and mark them with bean validation constraints like `@NotNull`.

> My question is, is there anyway of either checking the JSON for all
>   values or having Jackson through some sort of exception if a JSON key
>   is missing?

In my opinion, add Bean Validation constraints to your `POJO`s and then perform validations on incoming representations. If there was at least one constraint violation, Dropwizard will return a `422 Unprocessable` Entity response.

Suppose you have a `Person` like:

```
public class Person {

    @NotEmpty // ensure that name isn't null or blank
    private String name;

    @NotNull @Min(18) // at least 18 years old!
    private Integer age;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then, in our resource class, we can add the `@Valid` or the `@Validated` annotation to the `Person`:

```
@PUT
public Person replace(@Valid Person person) {
    // do stuff
}
```

If the *name* or *age* fields were missing, Dropwizard will return a `422 Unprocessable` Entity response detailing the validation errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Ill give that a try. I have used the NotEmpty annotation previously to no affect, but I did not know that you had to also mark the resource with Valid. 

Thanks again :)